# Parsing a jsonrray into object using moshi with Retrofit and Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin, moshi

I am trying to parse using  Moshi Library for JSON Array using Kotlin Coroutines .

Code use

```
 fun retrofitIndia(baseUrl : String) : Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(clientIndia)
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .build()
```

I get issue while Parsing the data class for JSON Array . I have used same for JSON Object and it works fine but during array , it crashes 
Below is the crash line

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for java.util.ArrayList<data.india.Delta2>
```

I call from Globallaunch coroutine where it gets failed

Code :

```
 GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val statsRequest = i.getStats()
            try {
                val response = statsRequest.await()
               if(response.){
                    val statsResponse = response.body() //This is single object Tmdb Movie response


                    Log.i("stats",""+statsResponse)
                }else{
                    Log.d("MainActivity ",response.errorBody().toString())
                }
            }catch (e: Exception){
                Log.e("Exception",e.localizedMessage)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide from which line the error is thrown? or show full stacktrace?

Comment: I have a jsonArray as a json output to be consumed ...

My error gets here when I call it from Kotlin Coroutine

  GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val statsRequest = iservice.getStats()
            try {
                val response = statsRequest.await()
               if(response.){
                    val statsResponse = response.body() //This is single object Tmdb Movie response


                   }
        }

Comment: @AnimeshSahu : Any idea of parsing JSONArray from Moshi ?

Comment: Don't know man, didn't worked with those libs, bounty the question maybe, take +1.

Comment: What is your JSON response format (example json response) and parser class.? Also full stacktrace would be helpful..

Answer (score 3):

You should make the type just `List<T>`, Moshi only supports the collection interfaces, not the concrete collection classes like `ArrayList<T>`, `LinkedList<T>`, etc.. The same goes for other kinds of collections: use `Set<T>` instead of `HashSet<T>`, and `Map<K, V>` instead of `HashMap<K, V>`, etc..

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the coroutines have anything with the parsing error, try following [Reading Json lists using Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/recipes/ReadJsonList.java)

Quick snippet will look something like:

```
// Single item declaration 
class SingleListItem(val title: String, val number: Int)

private var listMyData = Types.newParameterizedType(MutableList::class.java, SingleListItem::class.java)
private val adapter: JsonAdapter<List<SingleListItem>> = Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build().adapter(listMyData)
```